# Android Handler definition syntax

Tags: java, android, syntax

I recently found this code from a book on Android services:

```
static Handler UIupdater = new Handler() {
   @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      byte[] buffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
      //---convert the entire byte array to string---
      String strReceived = new String(buffer);
      //---display the text received on the TextView---
      txtView1.setText(strReceived);
      Log.d(“Threading”, “running”);
   }
};
```

I think I understand the purpose, -they just want to override the method of the Handler class without defining a subclass of it-, but I am not sure I understand the syntax. Actually, I never came across this kind of syntax in java before. Can someone point out the java mechanism involved here? In the beginning I thought it was anonymous inner classes but the static Handler UIupdater part makes me doubt about that...

Thanks for the help (sorry for the noob question)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, that's an [anonymous](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) [inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html), the instance of which is being assigned to the [static field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) `UIupdater`.

Comment: you are right!I was a bit confused about the Handler UIupdater part because in my mind I thought I had to subclass that class and override the handleMessage() method.